# rollup on only one column but groupby on more than one column in mysql

Tags: mysql

this is just a simple requirement - I want to use group by on more than one column but the result of rollup should be for only that column not on all the other columns.

```
select if( b.name is null,'--NO BOARD--',b.name)  board, count(u.id) 
from Usernow u
join School s on (s.id =u.id)
left join PreviousBoard b on (b.id= s.board )
where u.autoRegistered = 0
and u.createTime between :d_startDate and :d_endDate
group by 1,2 with rollup;
```

this creates unnecessary rows inthe end apart from the rollup row.

Can rollup be used in a more efficient way with group by ?

Thanks in advance!

```
class_no    class   count(u.id)
1   CBSE    -2  UKG 3
2   CBSE    -3  LKG 5
3   CBSE    -4  Nursery 4
4   CBSE    1   I   577
5   CBSE    10  X   196
6   CBSE    11  XI  45
7   CBSE    12  XII 33
8   CBSE    2   II  211
9   CBSE    3   III 126
10  CBSE    4   IV  128
11  CBSE    5   V   128
12  CBSE    6   VI  170
13  CBSE    7   VII 243
14  CBSE    8   VIII121
15  CBSE    9   IX  18
16  CBSE        IX  2008
17              IX  2008
```

have a look the result has ended at 15 only but still there are two confusing rows at the end due to that group on two columns with rollup.

Comment: try just **group by 1** (don't include 2nd column in the group by clause)

Comment: I prefer to do the roll up in application code - e.g. Php or JavaScript

Comment: @Used_By_Already.. bro,i have to use group by on both the columns ,it's the part of the requirement. grouping both of them has their uses..

Comment: @Strawberry.. it ain't a part of an application dude,it's being in a report

Comment: Almost nobody uses a MySQL command line interface to view reports.

Comment: Column 2 (as shown) is **COUNT(u.id)** i.e. this is an aggregation, not a grouping structure. Perhaps your query in he question has been oversimplified?

Comment: @Strawberry ..adding to my pains,my company does ..:-(

Comment: @Used_By_Already.. u are right ...i just wanted to handle that part dude,that is why i have simplified it .... i just wanted to know if we can use rollup with grouping on more than one columns...

Comment: Yes, you can rollup by multiple columns, but you may find that you get more rows than you desire.  In future try to make any simplified example match your real question, *we can only assess by what is on this page*.